# Gephi: display modularity in data laboratory

Tags: modularity, gephi

I use Gephi 0.9.1 and 0.9.2. I run modularity and have a number of class. When right-clicking on a node, I choose select in data laboratory. In a youtube tutorial, one got an extra column with modularity which allowed identification of modularity and export to csv files for further processing, lists, etc.
Is this possible?

Comment: Just wanted to add that if I run HITS, I do get 2 extra columns for Authority and Hub in the data laboratory.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that the number of displayed columns is limited. So one has to deselect some of the default ones if one wants additional columns to show up.